# How to apply assert condition to change list?

Tags: list, ocaml, assert

For this method I am supposed to duplicate the elements of a list that satisfy the condition that is expressed in the assert statement. Here is the skeleton:

```
let rec cond_dup l f =
  (* YOUR CODE HERE *)
   raise (Failure "Not implemented")
assert (cond_dup [3;4;5] (fun x -> x mod 2 = 1) = [3;3;4;5;5])
```

For some reason my code keeps failing, but i don't understand why. I am currently learning OCaml but I am having  difficult time understanding it especially when there are one or more assert statements. Here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
let rec cond_dup l f =
  (* YOUR CODE HERE *)
  match l with  
  | [] -> []
  |h::[] -> 
    if f h then h::h::[]
    else h::[]
  |h::t -> 
    if f h then h::h::(cond_dup t f)
    else (cond_dup t f)

  let f()= raise (Failure "Not implemented1")

let f() = assert (cond_dup [3;4;5] (fun x -> x mod 2 = 1) = [3;3;4;5;5])
;;

Please if you can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.
```

Comment: Since `(cond_dup [] f) == []` there is no need to special case `h::[]` in the match statement. The `h::t` case can handle t being [] just fine. This is generally true for recursive list processing. Just let the recusion run till it hits [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code duplicates the elements that satisfy the predicate. But it's also supposed to leave unchanged the elements that don't satisfy the predictate. You are deleting those elements instead. Think about the last line of your function. That's where the deletion (effectively) is happening.

(Since your code is effectively copying the list with modifications, the way to delete an element is simply not to include it in the copy. That's what you're doing.)

As a side comment, there's nothing fancy or mysterious going on with the `assert`. It's just a line of code that tests whether your function works for one particular input. If the assert fails, your function has an error.

Comment: So was doing f h in the if statements unnecessary? I could have just wrote h? And thank you I believe I understand what is wrong with my last line.

Comment: You need to call `f h` to decide whether to duplicate the value h or not. So the call is necessary.

Comment: He's talking about `else h::[]` (correct) vs. `else (cond_dup t f)` (where did the `h` go?).